# Breadcrumb doesn't generate any content

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I placed breadcrumb block to my page, but Breadcrumb doesn't generate any content. The pages are link in the menu, but it is still empty. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't know what is necessary to configure. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Which theme are you using? Did you try clearing caches? Did you try changing the theme? Always try switching back to one of the core themes; if the feature you're testing works there, it's caused by the theme you are using.

Comment: I'm using my custom theme. I tried to switch theme and in bartik it works.

Comment: Good; you narrowed the problem. In which region are you trying to show breadcrumbs? Is that region included in `page.html.twig`?

Comment: Region is correct and block is placed but page.breadcrumb is empty.

Comment: If it works on a core theme, but not your theme, the problem is in your theme. That's as much as can be said from here (for hopefully obvious reasons)

Comment: My mistake, I had in page.html.twig don't show the breadcrumb for frontpage and in block configuration show block only for frontpage. now I see breadcrumb, but it generates only Link to home. How it works, I couldn't find any info about it.